# Can I fetch keys by prefix and then delete them?

Tags: tokyo-cabinet

I can use `fwmkeys` to iterate over keys that share a prefix -- but how can I modify these keys as I iterate?  In my case I only need to be able to delete them or set them to empty, either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.  `fwmkeys` returns the key strings, so I can then operate directly on them that way.